# Examples of (classical) measurements that are not independent?

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, measurements

What are some simple examples of measurements that are not statistically independent, i.e. with nonzero covariance?  I'm looking for real examples that might reasonably come up in an undergraduate laboratory, for the purpose of illustrating experimental covariance.

To clarify:  if N measurements of quantities X and Y are $x_i$ and $y_i$, with means $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$, then the deviations are $x_i-\bar{x}$ and $y_i-\bar{y}$, and the covariance is the correlation of the deviations:  $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y}) \right]$.  The two measurements are statistically independent if this is 0.  I'm looking for examples of X and Y where this might not be 0.

Comment: Put two red balls in one bag and two blue balls in another. Don't tell the students which bag is which, and have a student pick a ball out of one random bag. Now ask what the statistics are of the the color of a second ball picked out of the same bag.

Comment: @DanielSank Thanks, but that's more of an example to illustrate the statistical principle, not a measurement that's likely to come up in lab.  (Also, I'm not exactly clear how your example illustrates covariance, rather than, say, Bayesian statistics.)

Comment: I understand what you mean about relevance to experimental lab, but could you explain what you mean exactly by "covariance"? For example, suppose I measure the mass of an object in several different ways. Does the correlation of the measurements with one another for a given object illustrate what you want?

Comment: Perhaps I understand what you're asking for: you don't want examples of correlated means, you actually want examples where the measurement fluctuations are correlated. I was confused because the first line of your question asks for measurements which are "not statistically independent." I think you should edit that out to make it clear that you're looking for correlated *fluctuations*, at least, if that *is* what you're looking for.

Comment: @DanielSank Yes, although I would not necessarily call the deviations from the mean of a measurement "fluctuations" (which to me implies variations in time).  But "not statistically independent" means the deviations from the mean of one measurement are correlated with the deviations from the mean of another measurement.

Comment: Ok, in that case can you help us help you? Given the large number of examples here and the fact that you aren't satisfied, I think maybe the question isn't quite asking what you meant to ask. Where is our communication breaking down?

Answer (score 1):

## Super simple generic example

Think of any quantity which you can measure by more than one technique.
Get one sample where that quantity has value $X$ and another sample where that quantity has value $Y$.
Have the students measure the parameter in a few different ways.
The measurements for sample $X$ will show correlation with one another, and the measurements for sample $Y$ will show correlation with one another.

## Electrical example

Get an approximately white noise source (i.e. a hot resistor) and capture a time trace on the oscilloscope.
The low pass filtering of the oscilloscope's analog input causes the measured voltages to be correlated in time.
You can use different filters to show the students that the correlation time of the voltage increases as the filter upper cutoff frequency is lowered.$^{[a]}$
If you have a spectrum analyzer you can relate the frequency domain spectral density to the time domain correlation time.
This is a great demo because the students can visually see the correlation of the measurements on the scope screen.

In this example the mean voltage measured at any particular time is zero.
You can establish this by simply computing the mean voltage from a series of samples on the scope.
With the *same dataset* you can see that samples close in time are correlated.
I really like this because it shows that a single set of data contains interesting statistical structure.

## Mechanical example

Start a pendulum swinging.
Without stopping the pendulum, have the students measure the pendulum's position at equally spaced times.
They will find that the measurements are indeed correlated.
In fact, they can compute the correlation function and will find that it is sinusoidal.
This may seem like a trivial example but it really isn't, especially if you then go to large displacements where the motion is not harmonic!

Like the electrical example, this shows a nice contrast between mean and correlation.
If the students plot a histogram of their measured values they'll find a zero mean (assuming they don't measure with frequency commensurate with the oscillation!), but then if they look at measurements with various time differences they see nonzero correlation.

If you want a correlation which isn't in the same variable at different times (i.e. not an autocorrelation) you can measure the position of the pendulum and the tension in the string (use a spring scale as a tension-ometer).

## Something which isn't an autocorrelation

Build an emitter-follower circuit with a BJT.
Measure the base current and collector current on the oscillscope.
Their fluctuations will be correlated.
You could in principle watch the gain change as temperature is varied.
Whether you regard that as correlated drift (which wouldn't really be a cross-correlation about a mean value as described by the formula in the OP) or as a real fluctuation about the mean depends on how you like to think about the time scales in the experiment.
This could actually be a good lesson for the students.

$[a]$: You can build different filters with just an $RC$ circuit. You can also probably just change the scope's input bandwidth, which requires a lot less effort :)

Comment: Thanks!  Your generic example and mechanical example are not examples of what I'm looking for, but the electrical example gives me an idea for one:  temperature readings from a thermistor will not be statistically independent of the current elsewhere in the same circuit.

Comment: @pwf Happy to help. Indeed, my examples were correlations in time whereas I gather from your comment that you are apparently looking for correlations in anything *other* than time. I would encourage you, in the name of pedagogy, to emphasize that both time and "other" correlations can be understood in the same general way. In particular this may help students when they get to statistical mechanics and have to understand ideas like the ergodic hypothesis, etc.

Comment: I'm looking for correlations between any two *different* measurements.  Your examples indicate autocorrelations.  I'd be happy for an example with time as one measurement (with deviations about a mean), but would want a second measurement whose deviations about a mean correlate with the time deviations (e.g. in instances when time is overmeasured, the other measurement tends also to be overmeasured).

Comment: @pwf: I see what you mean, but there isn't *really* a difference between measuring something at two different points in time and measuring two different things at the same time. They're both correlations. The fact that one is called "autocorrelation" is probably just due to the fact that many laws of physics are written as differential equations with time derivatives. I get your point though.

Answer (score 0):

## Astronomy example

Starting the day after a full moon, observe the time the Moon rises and estimate the fraction of the Moon that is illuminated. The time and illumination will be highly correlated, but the correlation won't be perfect because the relationship is not quite linear. A circular orbit would give a nice linear relationship. The Moon's orbit isn't quite circular, and even the Keplerian approximation of an ellipse isn't perfect because of solar and other perturbations. Correlation only looks for linear relationships.